# R subscript out of bounds corrected?

Tags: r, matrix

I generated the following data matrix called arrayDataMatrixQuantile in R:

```
DNp73flflV2324I DNp73flflV2324J DNp73flflV2324K DNp73nullV2523B DNp73nullV2523C DNp73nullV2523E
ENSMUSG00000028180        8.185794       5.6914560        5.693373       6.9734687       8.8689120       5.9152113
ENSMUSG00000028182        0.000000       0.1749128        0.000000       0.1685122       0.1784736       0.1229401
ENSMUSG00000028185        0.000000       0.0000000        0.000000       0.0000000       0.0000000       0.0000000
ENSMUSG00000028184        7.439927       8.8635180       10.288115      11.8621800      13.4530467      13.4414667
ENSMUSG00000028187        7.458357      10.0175407       14.108493      11.7789400      19.7581400      12.1482933
ENSMUSG00000028186        0.400568       0.1346390        3.450423       0.1643176       0.0000000       0.0000000
```

I want to generate log2 of each of the values and output that. The R code I wrote:

```
log2_matrix<-matrix( nrow(arrayDataMatrixQuantile),ncol(arrayDataMatrixQuantile)) #opens new matrix
for (i in 1:nrow(arrayDataMatrixQuantile)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(arrayDataMatrixQuantile)) {
        add <- ((arrayDataMatrixQuantile[i,j])+10^-5) #Added 10-5 to avoid errors with 0 values
    log2_matrix[i,j] <-add }
}
```

This code gives the following error:

#### Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = 2.50880030780749) : subscript out of bounds

However, once I change the line :

```
log2_matrix<-matrix( nrow(arrayDataMatrixQuantile),ncol(arrayDataMatrixQuantile))
```

to

```
log2_matrix<-matrix(0, nrow(arrayDataMatrixQuantile),ncol(arrayDataMatrixQuantile))
```

it works. I dont know how adding a "0" in the new matrix gets rid of the error. I used that as I saw other users adding a 0 at the start of each new matrix. Any advise on this?

Comment: Try `apply(arrayDataMatrixQuantile, 2, FUN=function(x)  x+ 10^-5)`

Comment: Thanks. It works, but still, i dont get why 0 would fix the issue in my initial code. It is something i am encountering a lot. Any advice on that?

Comment: If you check the code `matrix( nrow(arrayDataMatrixQuantile),ncol(arrayDataMatrixQuantile))`, it has dimensions 6, 1 and the values are 6.  So, instead, you need to add  `,` before the `nrow(array..` so that it will return a 6*6 matrix of `NA`  The usage of `matrix` is `matrix(data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE,
       dimnames = NULL)` In the first case, the `data` part was not given

Comment: OH!! ok. finally this is clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this either using `apply`

```
apply(arrayDataMatrixQuantile, 2, FUN=function(x) x+ 10^-5)
```

Or directly add the number to the entire dataset

```
arrayDataMatrixQuantile+10^-5
```

---

Regarding the error in the OP's code, it happened because the `matrix` created was not of the same dimensions as the "arrayDataMatrixQuantile"

```
 log2_matrix<- matrix( nrow(arrayDataMatrixQuantile),
             ncol(arrayDataMatrixQuantile))
```

The "log2_matrix" doesn't have a `data` argument and its dimensions are `6,1` with 6 as the value (from the `nrow(...`)).  Instead, we need to add a `,` before the `nrow(..)` so that we get a `matrix` of NA with dimensions `6,6`

```
  log2_matrix <- matrix(, nrow(arrayDataMatrixQuantile),
                      ncol(arrayDataMatrixQuantile))
```